# check for error while reading file though fgets()

Tags: c, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception, fgets

I want to know how I would detect an error on `fgets()`, I am writing test class, so I want to check whether the user entered the wrong buffer size on `fgets()`, and I want to display a message and do not make the program exit on its own

```
char a[10];

fgets(a,100,stdin);
```

I want to make the program exit on status 2 as I will clarify that error happens

Comment: It is not a matter of the _user_ entering the wrong buffer size.  In you example the programmer has made the error.  You are asking for a runtime check for a compile time error.

Comment: this will result of stack smashing detected, I do not want the program to exit on that. I need to display other message

Comment: You can't; you corrupt the stack, your code will no longer behave normally, so you cannot guarantee that any handling code will run normally.  In fact it is not a given even that the OS will detect it - it is not defined by the language for which no bounds checking is performed.   The OS will detect it only if invalid memory is accessed.  Some debuggers will perform checks.  You have to detect the error _before_ it happens.  It is a clear coding error, that is where you need to fix it.  Allowing a user to enter 100 bytes, but providing a buffer of only 10 is _your_ error, not the user's.

Comment: I know it is a programmer error, I want to detect that as well,

Comment: That's not what you have asked.

Answer (score 1):

The programming issue is better solved by good programming practices, static analysis, testing and debugging *before* letting users loose on it.  The kind of errors you need to write code for are those that can happen at runtime because of erroneous *input*.  If you write undetected bugs in your code, writing *more code* to detect them makes little sense.

In your example, a better coding practice to mitigate the chances of coding error is:

```
char a[10] ;

fgets( a, sizeof(a), stdin ) ;
```

Comment: @bigdataolddriver `fgets()` returns pointer, `a` or a null pointer.  `fgets()` does not return a  char.